# doubt in enum declaration

Tags: java, enums

can i make my enum private or protected. for ex

```
enum day{sun,mon,tue};
```

this is what we usually give. Can i give like

```
private enum day{mon,..};
```

Comment: what for? which should be private - the enum class, or the enum constant?

Comment: the best way to learn to try. Try things your self and see the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can put access modifiers in front of enums, just as you can with classes.

This snippet compiles just fine:

```
class Main {
    enum SomePkgEnum { A, B, C };
    public enum SomePubEnum { A, B, C };
    private enum SomePrivEnum { A, B, C };
    protected enum SomeProtEnum { A, B, C };
}

// Top-level enum: Only public (or package level) access allowed.
public enum SomeOtherEnum { A, B, C };
```